# Как проверить точку на принадлежность многоугольника?

Tags: геометрия

Есть многоугольник произвольный формы, известны координаты вершин. Как мне рандомно выбрать случайную точку, чтобы она была именно **в нём**, а не на границе или вовсе вне её области.

На данный момент продумал так

1) Брать самую высокую, самую нижнюю, самую правую, самую левую и соединить их так, чтобы фигура "влезла" в прямоугольник.

2) Брать из прямоугольника случайные точки

3) Проверять на принадлежность многоугольнику

4) Если не принадлежит - повторить.

Но что-то не пойму как третье выполнить.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Классическая проверка на принадлежность точки многоугольнику - из неё пускается луч, и считается количество пересечений со сторонами многоугольника (на самом деле считают количество сторон-отрезков, имеющих с лучом общую точку). Если оно чётно - точка снаружи иначе внутри. Что она не на стороне - проверяется отдельно.

Для простоты программной реализации луч пускают только горизонтальный (или только вертикальный). И контролируют, что ни одна из сторон не лежит на луче.